# Window manager not loading when gnome-classic starts

Tags: gnome-classic

When I boot up or log into gnome-classic (no effects), windows don't have the frame around them that has the minimize and close buttons and all that. After that, there all sorts of issues - for example, when I open a new window, it's in the very top left corner, obscuring the menu on the gnome panel... just a whole bunch of minor annoyances.

I can get things working by by loading the compiz fusion icon and then selecting to reload the window manager.

Of course this is less than ideal. How do I get the window manager to load automatically?

**Update:** It seems that I get no window manager whenever I load Compiz, even after logging in. So it looks like the problem is more generally with Compiz's window manager.

Comment: I have this problem too and `compiz --replace` doesn't help. I'm running lightdm, could that be the problem? Also, where could I tell gnome-classic which window manager it should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 2012, this problem was resolved automatically with subsequent updates to Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

First install dconf editor OR tweak (advanced settings) to add the extra buttons on the title bar

For the windows manager problemn, if you think that for some reason it's related to lightdm, try installing gdm.

Answer (score 1):

Go to > system > preferences > start up applications.

Create a new application launcher and add.

Make sure the command is `compiz --replace` so it starts every time

[image]